# Malicious code hidden in image

Tags: image, iis, asp-classic, virus

I've come across a dodgy file upload on our server. It is an image and the MIME TYPE checks out, though on the server it was also uploaded with the extension .asp and .cer.

On the surface its a photo some weird chinese symbols and the letters asp, though I am sure it is hiding malicious code. I did a google search by image and it came out in a few possibly unsecure directories in some other sites.

This is out of my league to even verify. Out of interest I opened the file in notepad and it has the clear string "Google" which only makes me believe more that it is malicious.

All I need to know is

1- is it malicious?
 2-did it run and what did it do?
 3- how do i protect against it?

I cant give the link to the actual file on my server since Its been removed, but I can zip and mail it to anyone who wants to take a look.

If anyone has some advise on where to start I would appreciate it.

Heres a link to the same image, which came up on my google search though this one most likely has different code injected

http://www.bakjuweel.be/ShowImage.aspx?img=/upload/fotogalerijen/13/3.asp;.jpg&w=135&h=111

UPDATE

After alot more research I have found that it had a modified header to inject code. I run it through virustotal.com and my suspicious were confirmed. https://www.virustotal.com/en/file/3eac6e45d5923632089b538ca86d576c9994bd25be7940165ec997484d7c6715/analysis/

What it does or whether it executed is still unknown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, the file was malicious it contained encoded php, all of which im not sure of there were far too many encoded layers. It created a backdoor that fetched and executed remote code. This file was not detected by any of our antivirus software, what gave it away way was <% eval(. was the only part not encoded.A hacker took advantage of a vunerability in an old version of FCKeditor to add and execute it. I am still looking for a way to prevent it in the future.